# Vim style Omnicomplete for emacs?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, elisp, omnicomplete

I've found several code completion elisp packages for emacs that do code completion, but most bind to a key such as M-/ to toggle completion.  Is there something similar to Vim's omnicomplete where you can set it to automatically pop up a list of autocompletion options where you can either navigate through them, or just keep typing.

See screenshot for example:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think [company mode](http://nschum.de/src/emacs/company-mode/) would best fit your description. Have a look at it.

Comment: Awesome! I need to get company mode!

Comment: Use autocomplete instead. It is newer and more complete than company-mode

Answer (score 5):

There are a number, all a little different:

- [predictivemode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PredictiveMode)
- [pabbrev](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PredictiveAbbreviation)
- [completionui](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CompletionUI)
- [autocomplete](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete)

They all have their drawbacks and advantages.

The emacs wiki has a page for all the [completion packages](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryCompletion).

Answer (score 1):

Can you? Sure.  Reset a timer on post-command-hook.  If it goes off (because you are sitting at your screen not typing), pop-up the thing.

It seems easier to tell your computer what to do (by pressing keys) rather than having it wait for your to stop typing for a while, however.  Bind completion to something like the "menu key", and you won't even have to chord.